# Is there any solution to log if somebody get my website's pages with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, database

For example somebody get data from my website with file_get_contents, on his local computer, upload data to his DB and after upload this DB to a server?
Sorry for my bad English...
Thank you for your replay!

Comment: Simple answer is that this is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web server should log the requests whether they came via file_get_contents or any other way. You can check the logs to see if there is anything distinctive about these requests (like the IP they are coming from or the user agent string).

Once the information is downloaded, it is now out of the control of your server and so you will not be able to log if the data is uploaded to a DB or other server.

Comment: All of that can be faked.